# negative gaussian curvature surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

> > I am looking for examples of surfaces $M$ with gaussian curvature $K\lt0$ Additionally, a closed geodesic lies on the surface $M$

Thanks

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32597/compact-surfaces-of-negative-curvature), or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828277/ruled-surface-of-constant-k-gauss-curvature) for examples. Also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces) gives examples.

Comment: @DietrichBurde the links dont give an answer to the second part of my questions. There is a closed geodesic $\gamma $ on $M$